# Redirect a request to a colud server from a godady server with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5.6, domain-forwarding

Hi everyone need your support with the following problem. Please do apologies if I confuse you in anyways with my explanation.

I have a add-on domain (example.com) pointed to a Godaddy Linux server, domain is also in the Godaddy same account.

The web application for "example.com" is a Laravel 5.6 based one, and the web app has 'Get' type search form which needs to be forwarded to another Windows IIS server's port with all the query strings where another web app is hosted. the action of the from will be similar to below.

```
Request => http://sub1.example.com/route/method?var=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3
```

From this point on-wards the application has to continue work from the IIS server with the subdomain, which mean I am not expecting any replies from this IIS server to the Linux server.

Its been advised to use the subdomain to mask the forwarding to the IIS server, so I did like above with sub1 sub-domain. This subdomain has to be forwarded to a server's port as I mentioned above, something similar to below.

```
http://sub1.example.com => http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:9596
```

I did tried with the Godaddy's default subdomain forwarding with masking, but the query strings are not being forwarded and shows "Destination Unknown" error.

In a online forum its been advised not to go with Godaddy's forwarding instead go with .htaccess to have more control.

Therefore any possible solutions or your support with the redirection with .htaccess from web application to the external web server's specific port along with the query strings would be a life saver.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the GoDaddy support, the domain forwarding to a IP's port is **not possible with the Shared hosting**.

The support suggested to go-ahead with the VPS and configure.

Please do comment, if this is wrong statement!